# How to get time from datetime into a string/number for a colormap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, colorbar

I'm trying to shade a scatter plot based on time of day, but my data is in datetime format. Getting either time of day or hours past 00:00 would work. I tried to get just the time from datetime, but I got the following error.

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

Ideally, I'll have a scatterplot shaded based on time of day.

I initially tried this (also added .values to the end of the dt.time to see if it would help. It didn't).

```
x = dfbelow[1:].wind_speed.values
y = above_aligned["WS"].values
plt.scatter(x, y, s=20, c=above_aligned["timestamp"].dt.time, cmap='YlOrBr')

plt.xlabel("Below Canopy Wind Speed (m/s)")
plt.ylabel("Above Canopy Wind Speed (m/s)")
plt.title("Above vs. Below Canopy Wind Speeds (m/s)")
plt.colorbar(label="Below Canopy Wind Direction")
plt.show
```

But it understandably can't shade based off of a datetime form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it was actually very simple. Instead of above_aligned["timestamp"].dt.time, I just used above_aligned["timestamp"].dt.hour.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to calculate hours passed midnight you can use matplot dates module to convert time to the numeric representative and plot it:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

time_values = [mdates.date2num(timestamps = above_aligned["timestamp"]) % 1 for timestamp in timestamps]

# Create scatter plot with colormap based on time of day
plt.scatter(x, y, s=20, c=time_values, cmap='YlOrBr')
```

[Matplotlib refrence](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num)

Answer (score 0):

**Try `datetime.hour` or `datetime.timestamp()`**

`datetime.hour` returns the hour part of the time:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt.hour
9
```

`datetime.timestamp()`, note the parentheses, it's a method, returns a large float, in seconds from the epoch:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> dt.timestamp()
1685723937.569643
```

Alternatively, you could use `datetime.time()`:

```
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> s = dt.time()
>>> s.hour * 60 + s.minute
578  # Minutes since 00:00
```